# Why doesn't my edittext change it content?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to change the content of the edittext megapixel to be the product of the width and height text boxes to make a megapixel calculator.

```
public void calculate()
{

    EditText tb_widthpx = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtbox_widthpx);
    EditText tb_heightpx = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtbox_heigthpx);
    EditText tb_megapixel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtbox_megapixel);

    if (tb_widthpx.getText().toString() != "" && tb_heightpx.getText().toString() !="")
    {
        int produkt;
        int width = Integer.parseInt(tb_widthpx.getText().toString());
        int height = Integer.parseInt((tb_heightpx.getText().toString()));

        produkt = width * height;
        tb_megapixel.setText(String.valueOf(produkt));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Java` you have to use `.equals()` so try this,

```
public void calculate()
{

    EditText tb_widthpx = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtbox_widthpx);
    EditText tb_heightpx = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtbox_heigthpx);
    EditText tb_megapixel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtbox_megapixel);

    if (!tb_widthpx.getText().toString().equals("") && !tb_heightpx.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        int produkt;
        int width = Integer.parseInt(tb_widthpx.getText().toString());
        int height = Integer.parseInt((tb_heightpx.getText().toString()));

        produkt = width * height;
        tb_megapixel.setText(String.valueOf(produkt));
    }
```

Reference: [Why you use .equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: However this still doesnt solve my original problem but thanks for the remark.

Comment: I just solved it on my own. I idiot didn't connect the onclick to the button. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.equals()` to compare Strings. Like this:

```
if (!tb_widthpx.getText().toString().equals("") && !tb_heightpx.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    int produkt;
    int width = Integer.parseInt(tb_widthpx.getText().toString());
    int height = Integer.parseInt((tb_heightpx.getText().toString()));

    produkt = width * height;
    tb_megapixel.setText(String.valueOf(produkt));
}
```

But for a better performance you should use `.length()`. Like this:

```
if (!tb_widthpx.getText().toString().length() == 0 && !tb_heightpx.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
    int produkt;
    int width = Integer.parseInt(tb_widthpx.getText().toString());
    int height = Integer.parseInt((tb_heightpx.getText().toString()));

    produkt = width * height;
    tb_megapixel.setText(String.valueOf(produkt));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but this doesnt solve my problem.

Comment: I just solved it on my own. I idiot didn't connect the onclick to the button. Sorry.